# Changing Look and Feel of Swing controls

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application, look-and-feel

I am going to start developing a desktop application in Java. For that I require to provide customized controls to the customer. I searched out on internet about overriding Swing controls but didn't find any useful stuff. They provided ready-made look and feel like nimbus and etc. My question is how to customize Swing controls to change their Look and Feel?

Comment: you can read this article : How to Write a Custom Look and Feel http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/09/12/how-to-write-custom-look-and-feel.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look here  http://www.javasoft.de/synthetica/customize/. "The tables below contain useful UI-defaults which can be set by the UIManager for customizing a Synthetica look and feel programmatically. Use UIManager#put(Object key, Object value) for changing values."

Comment: those are very special to synthetica (which - biased me - thinks a cool LAF, it's comercial though)